# ¿Cómo controlar el número total de repeticiones de dos hilos?

Tags: java

Tengo un método tomando como argumento un ID de entero y devolviendo un objeto Ejecutable `Runable` (como clase anónima) que redefine el método para mostrar 10,000 veces "Yo soy el ID de los thread" (O id coincide al entero pasado en el parámetro).

En el método main (), quiero crear dos objetos `Threads`, con el argumento del constructor `Runnables` creado por el método anterior con `id = 1` e `id = 2`.

Quiero agregar un entero n en la clase ThreadTest de subprocesos y modificar el bucle para que el número total de iteraciones (todos los subprocesos combinados) sea igual a 10000.

Intenté lo siguiente pero parece que no imprime lo que le pido en la excepción.

```
class ThreadTest implements Runnable {

    private int id;
    public static int n;

    public ThreadTest(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try{
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                if(n >=1000){
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                }else{
                    n+=1;
                    System.out.println(" Je suis le thread d'id " + this.id);
                }
            }           
        }catch(InterruptedException exception){
            System.out.println(" n " + n);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadTest(1));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadTest(2));

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: cuando n llega a 1000 los dos threads se paran eternamente?

Comment: @gbianchi Yo tengo la impresión. Pero no tengo la confirmación en la medida en que no tengo el mensaje que se supone que se muestra con la excepción.

Comment: sale por el catch? y no imprime nada?

Comment: No estoy familiarizado en como lo hace java.. pero hace los dos start, y el programa principal termina... o no?

Comment: ¿Imprimirlo en un finally no te ayuda?

Comment: @gbianchi Pienso que sale por el catch, pero no puede asegurarme porque no imprime nada. El programa termina cuando obtenemos ` Je suis le thread d'id ??? n : 10000`. Pero como se trata de dos hilos paralelos el ultimo puede ser `n = 9995` cuando uno de los que fueron escritos antes es `n = 10000`

Comment: Finally me permiti hacerlo